# Destructor call

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    int b;
public:
    A(){
        cout<<"Constructor for class A called\n";
        b = 6;
    }
    ~A(){
        cout<"Destructor called for class A\n";
    }
};

class B{
    A a;
public:
    B(){
        cout<<"Constructor for class B called\n";
    }
    ~B(){
        cout<<"Destructor called for class B\n";
    }
};


int main(void){
    B obj1;
    return 0;
}
```

When the above code is executed the **constructors** for both A and B are called as expected but when B's object i.e. obj1 goes out of scope only B's destructor is called. Why A's **destructor** is not called even though A's obj is one of the members of B ?

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks for reply. This is the original code. A's destructor is not called.

Comment: A's destructor is definitely called. Your code as is doesn't compile, see ~A().

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes it is called.But VS2010 didnt throw error for using single '<'.

Comment: That is working fine in g++....

Comment: @rahul not with gcc 4.6.2 or 4.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `<` in A's destructor:

```
 cout << "Destructor called for class A\n";
```

If you're not getting a compilation error for the expression:

```
 cout < "Destructor called for class A\n"
      |
 //less than operator
```

well, your compiler is trying to compare `cout` to a `const char*`. Which is a weird thing to do. But, alas, change `<` to `<<` and it should work: http://ideone.com/8TDyy

Comment: Thanks !!. Sorry for careless mistake. But wondering why compiler didnt throw error !!

Comment: @niting112 I am curious, what compiler are you using?

Comment: VS2010 gives a clear warning about it.  Which warning level are you compiling with?

Comment: `cout`, like any stream, converts implicitly to a pointer type (pre-C++11, anyway).  And you can compare pointer types.  C++11 changed the conversion to `bool`, so this shouldn't compile in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a < character in the destructor of A.

The line

```
cout<"Destructor called for class A\n";
```

just means: compare cout with the given string and return true or false.

You should write

```
cout<<"Destructor called for class A\n";
```

And then it works correctly.

It's better to add spaces before and after the << operator to make this clearer (I always say that code needs to breath (it needs some air)).

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows:

cout<"Destructor called for class A\n";

There should be two <<'s, not one. I'm surprised it compiles at all...

Comment: Well apparently leaving off one of the <'s is still valid c++. No error, just a warning in VS2010.

Comment: It's valid C++03, because of the implicit conversion of the stream to a pointer type.  A decent compiler will warn about an unused calculation.  It's invalid C++11, because the streams now convert to `bool`, rather than a pointer type, and comparing a `bool` with a pointer is not legal.

Answer (score 1):

```
~A(){
        cout<"Destructor called for class A\n";
    }
```

the operator to be used with cout is `<<` and not `<` its the less than operator
correct it and your code will be fine.

```
~A(){
        cout<<"Destructor called for class A\n";
    }
```